# Stepping into C++ OpenCV source

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-debugging, object-detection

I have downloaded OpenCV 2.4.4 and visual studio 2010. i am running some samples in the package from here [Peopledetect.cpp](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/changes/samples/cpp/peopledetect.cpp). I am able to compile and run the sample. what i want to do is step into the source file, Source file is mainly here [Hog.cpp](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/changes/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp). But i am not able to step into the source file. When i click go to definition/follow object under cursor i am able to go to definition which is(.hpp) which is [objectdetect.hpp](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/objdetect/include/opencv2/objdetect.hpp) file but unable to go to source files.

Can anyone give tips

Answer (score 0):

you need to rebuild the opencv libraries using cmake to build the *.pdb files for this.

once you link your exe against those ( not the prebuild libs ) you can step into the code while debugging